# dependent visa for japan

Tags: family, dependent-visa, japan

I am 24 years old, and my father, mother and sister are in japan they are from last 2 years. So I also want to join them. Is there any possibilities to get dependent visa via my mother ??

Comment: *join them* = go live with them, I assume? What are your nationalities?

Comment: What is your mother's status (it's written on her residence card)?

Comment: my mother is in working visa as a cook. Its been 2 years

Comment: You did not answer the question; we need to know her status as written on her residence card.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know there is no age limit on the dependent visa, but you do need to be a dependent. That means that you will depend on your mother for your lifestyle and you will not be able to work. If you're 24 years old it's probably better to try to find a way to get a working visa. If you have a university degree and you can find a Japanese employer that will sponsor you, that should be possible.

Comment: indeed, he (I assume) can be sponsored by his mom's visa (same expiration date). Then later he can find baito jobs which don't require working visa, also less income.